# std::ifstream read reading wrong size for large numbers

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, valgrind, ifstream

I have a Problem while reading a lare chunk of binary data from a file at once. Reading the same amount of bytes bytewise is working. I have to following sample code:

```
std::ifstream inFile;
inFile.open("example.bin", std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);
uint32_t bytesToAllocate = static_cast<uint32_t>(this->sectionLength)-4;
this->binaryData = new uint8_t[bytesToAllocate];
inFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&this->binaryData), bytesToAllocate);
```

if i run this code, it crashes with a Segmentation fault. The corresponding valgrind output is:

```
==13336== Invalid write of size 2
==13336==    at 0x4C3090B: memcpy@@GLIBC_2.14 (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==13336==    by 0x4EDB1F2: std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::xsgetn(char*, long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.20)
==13336==    by 0x4EF486D: std::basic_filebuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::xsgetn(char*, long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.20)
==13336==    by 0x4EB877A: std::istream::read(char*, long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.20)
==13336==    by 0x4038F4: Reader::readFile(std::string) (reader.cpp:145)
==13336==    by 0x401698: main (main.cpp:16)
==13336==  Address 0xfff001000 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

But when i read the same amount of date byte wise with the following code

```
for(int i=0; i< bytesToAllocate; ++i)
    inFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&this->binaryData[i]), 1);
```

The program runs and valgrind does not complain. In my case bytesToAllocate is 5370.

I hope this information is enough for someone to help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this->binaryData = new uint8_t[bytesToAllocate];
inFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&this->binaryData), bytesToAllocate);
```

You're reading into the address of `this->binaryData`. But the *value* of `this->binaryData` is the address you want. You want:

```
this->binaryData = new uint8_t[bytesToAllocate];
inFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(this->binaryData), bytesToAllocate);
```

Comment: argh stupid mistake, of course you are correct. Thanks for the fast answer.